# How can I do reflection of UIImage with water mark in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I wants to show reflection of uiimage with water mark.
Do I need to know openGLES for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this guide: http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/08/no-fuss-reflections/

For the watermark-part, I'm not sure what you mean. If you want the watermark to be reflected, it will.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. WaterMark meant The reflected image should look in water.

Comment: Well, I don't really know about that, but you're welcome. If you felt like this answer helped you, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as the accepted answer by clicking the ✔ next to it :)

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.